# How to target non-empty p elements in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a plugin for my WordPress site. I want to select all non-empty paragraph elements.

Here is my code :

```
function my_php_custom_function($content){

 // Create a new DOMDocument instance
 $dom = new DOMDocument();

 // Load the HTML content into the DOMDocument
 $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

 // Create a DOMXPath object to query the DOM
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

 // Find all non-empty p elements in the content
 $p_elements = $xpath->query('//p[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]');
}


add_filter('the_content','my_php_custom_function')
```

`$p_elements` in this variable I am getting those paragraphs also which I have just created by pressing enter. When I check on DOM, it is showing as `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not the result of a carriage return and `&nbsp;` evaluates correctly as non-empty. Where does your content of the `$content` variable come from?

Comment: I have updated my code @Repox. I don't want to target paragraphs which has only `&nbsp;'

Comment: Su just check if content is `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely using some sort of WYSIWYG editor for your content, which in some cases produce elements only containing `&nbsp;`

To get non-empty P elements and also ignoring P elements containing only `&nbsp;` your XPath could look like the following:

```
//p[normalize-space() and not(normalize-space(.) = '&nbsp;')]
```

**Updated answer:**

Apparently, the representation in the DOMDocument of the `&nbsp;` converts fully (via `bin2hex()` to `c2a0`. Using this knowledge, we can input it as the hexidecimal conversion instead (`\xC2\xA0`).

This would render your query to look somewhat like the following:

```php
$p_elements = $xpath->query('//p[normalize-space() and not(normalize-space(.) = "'."\xC2\xA0".'")]');
```

While not pretty (due to all the escaping), it works in my small tests.

Comment: I have tried this but it won't work as expected. I am still getting paragraph which has `&nbsp;` only. Here is my updated code :
`$p_elements = $xpath->query('//p[normalize-space() and not(normalize-space(.) = "&nbsp;")]');`